# Docker Compose use both host and bridge network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have 2 images that I want to talk to each other via compose's default bridge network, but I also want them to be able to access my host network.

To allow images to talk to each other within compose's default bridge network, I don't need to do anything:

```
version: '3.4'
services: 
  hello:
   image: hello-world

  world:
    image: hello-world
```

With the above spec, `hello` service could reference `world` service by using the DNS name `world`

If I wanted hello service to be able to interact with my host machine's network, I could add `network_mode: host` to the spec.

```
version: '3.4'
services: 
  hello:
   image: hello-world
   network_mode: host
  world:
    image: hello-world
```

This allows `hello` service to access my host machine's network, but can no longer access `world` via compose's built in DNS. How can I accomplish both?

I've tried creating a custom network, but custom networks can't use the host driver and I cannot use `network_mode` in combination with `networks`:

This doesn't work:

```
version: '3.4'
services: 
  hello:
   image: hello-world
   network_mode: host
   networks:
   - bridge
  world:
    image: hello-world
    networks:
    - bridge

networks:
  test:
    driver: bridge
```

```
$ docker-compose up
ERROR: 'network_mode' and 'networks' cannot be combined
```

Answer (score 0):

If they're both on your host network, they can talk to each other just like normal applications talk to each other: via localhost. So you don't need the bridge at all.